# Skip char in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need something like this (for '-' char):

when --- skip it, but when -- gives the position.

The problem is when ---, the -- is strating from the first char or the second one instead of skipping it.

What is the way to exclude --- from regex and continue to find the next -- in javascript regex ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please include the attempts you've made so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what's around the dashes but you could do this.

Note that JS does not support lookbehind, so you have to consume whats
before the dashes as well.

`(?:[^-]|$)--(?!-)`

Explanation

```
 (?:
      [^-]            # Not a dash
   |  ^               # or, beginning of string
 )
 --              # Two dashes
 (?! - )         # Not a dash after this
```

Comment: ```(?:[^-]|$)--(?!-)``` is working except if for example I write m--, then m is the first match char. I only want -- to be matched. Is there a way to skip the first char or exclude from the group ?

Comment: If you read what I wrote, that character cannot be excluded from the match. You can just add a capture group around the `--`, but why would you do that, the last two characters are -- so what's the difference

Comment: For now, the regex is (c = character) : c--... The group is --, but I need to remove c from it to let my tmLanguage starts from -- and not from c

Comment: position = lenth > 2 ? position+1 : position;

Comment: Impossible via regex for tmLanguage ?

Comment: Lookbehind impossible for JavaScript. You must consume a character. The position will be correct if you use a capture group and reference it.  `/(?:[^-]|$)(--)(?!-)/[1]` somehow.

Comment: I believe you meant `/(?:[^-]|^)(--)(?!-)/` (as in your explanation).

Comment: I'd use `/([^-]|^)(--)(?!-)/`.

Comment: Its up to you, but the other one would find %99.99 of them. Take your pick.